# Editing form with FileField removes the file

Tags: javascript, python, django

i have a `ModelForm` with dynamically generated fields
. Everything works fine, but the editing. The `input[type=file]` loses its file and instead, it puts it in the `<a href="/path/to/file">` called "currently". I think this is some kind of browser/HTML thing. When i submit the form i need those files in `request.FILES`.

This is how i define the initials of the file: `self.initial[field_name2] = admins[i].contract`

I wanted to handle it with `Javascript`, but it is not possible to change the value of `input[type=file]`.

I would post some code, but it is kinda long so i prefer not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Javascript for this.

Try to make hidden HTML input field with filename as value.
After POST check request.FILES first and if empty check request.POST with hidden field.